# passing the thread token

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, statemachines, week07

In the `firstGame` function, we use the "logging" component of the contract to `tell` the thread token. It's not obvious to me where this is needed: is there an internal check in the `runStep` function that this token matches the one in the parameter, i.e. `SecondParams`? I commented out the line where `tt` is `told` and that results in an endless loop, while I expected a failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **firstGame** is the contract that initialises the game, it needs to communicate somehow the generated **threadToken** to the external world (**secondGame** in this case). For this kind of communication **Contract** monad uses **tell** mechanism.

How does the info flow? You can see it in **myTrace** function in `Week07.TestStateMachine`.

- (1) `callEndpoint @"first" h1 fp` - Initialise the game, and **firstGame** contract internally tells the generated **threadToken** to anyone interested in it.
- (2) `tt <- getTT h1` - This function uses **observableState** function, which "get the observable state w of a contract instance". In our case **w** in **firstGame** Contract is **(Last ThreadToken)**.

```
   firstGame :: forall s. FirstParams -> Contract (Last ThreadToken) s Text ()
```

- (3) `let sp = SecondParams {...  spToken = tt ...}` - Build params for **secondGame** using **threadToken** generated by **firstGame** contract, **tt**.
- (4) `callEndpoint @"second" h2 sp` - **secondGame** plays.

**Notice that communication is not direct Contract to Contract but through observableState function**

```
myTrace :: GameChoice -> GameChoice -> EmulatorTrace ()
myTrace c1 c2 = do
    Extras.logInfo $ "first move: " ++ show c1 ++ ", second move: " ++ show c2

    let w1 = knownWallet 1
    let w2 = knownWallet 2

    h1 <- activateContractWallet w1 endpoints
    h2 <- activateContractWallet w2 endpoints

    let pkh1      = mockWalletPaymentPubKeyHash w1
        pkh2      = mockWalletPaymentPubKeyHash w2
        stake     = 5_000_000
        deadline1 = slotToEndPOSIXTime def 5
        deadline2 = slotToEndPOSIXTime def 10

        fp = FirstParams
                { fpSecond         = pkh2
                , fpStake          = stake
                , fpPlayDeadline   = deadline1
                , fpRevealDeadline = deadline2
                , fpNonce          = "SECRETNONCE"
                , fpChoice         = c1
                }

    callEndpoint @"first" h1 fp   -- (1)

    tt <- getTT                   -- (2)

    let sp = SecondParams         -- (3)
                { spFirst          = pkh1
                , spStake          = stake
                , spPlayDeadline   = deadline1
                , spRevealDeadline = deadline2
                , spChoice         = c2
                , spToken          = tt
                }

    void $ Emulator.waitNSlots 3  -- (4)

    callEndpoint @"second" h2 sp

    void $ Emulator.waitNSlots 10
  where
    getTT :: ContractHandle (Last ThreadToken) GameSchema Text -> EmulatorTrace ThreadToken
    getTT h = do
        void $ Emulator.waitNSlots 1
        Last m <- observableState      -- (2)
        case m of
            Nothing -> getTT h
            Just tt -> Extras.logInfo ("read thread token " ++ show tt) >> return tt
```

Comment: Ouch, my bad, I didn't look at the test. The getTT method also explains the loop when I comment out the tell.